# APC for windows alternative download

Tags: php, windows, installation, apc

I am trying to install APC on windows but the site http://pecl4win.php.net/ is down for a while now with the message:

> The pecl4win build box is temporarily out of service. We're preparing a new build system.

Is there an alternative download for this ?
Or can anyone share theirs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up-to-date builds could be found [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

Comment: Just for the record the link isn't working anymore.

Comment: try this http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html

Answer (score 23):

**Update:**

My answer below is outdated, and the `pierre` folder seems to be offline. You can now use [PECL :: Package Browser](https://pecl.php.net/packages.php), for example: [PECL :: Package :: APC](https://pecl.php.net/package/APC), which has DLLs listed.

**Old Answer:**

I got APC (and some other PECL packages') dll's for Win32 from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Not sure how permanent this source is, found it on some forum a while back and bookmarked it.

This is an old question, but I found it through a google search, so others might too!

Answer (score 5):

Versions up to 3.1.14 are available at [Win-Web-Dev](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html). Though they don't have the exact configuration I need of "APC 3.1.9/PHP 5.3/Apache, thread-safe, VC6". But they have several other configurations that work.

Answer (score 2):

The link of smautf is down, but you can find the same content of it (APC and another builds for Win) in http://downloads.php.net/pierre/. I neither know how permanent it is, but as july 25th (2009) it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the latest 3.1.9  nts (non thread safe for iis) from here (as of 2011-08-23) and am running it with IIS 7 on windows 2008: http://dev.freshsite.pl/download/file/details/apc-319-for-php-53-vc9-nts-win72008.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download the php extenstion at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, and download the extension. There are a lot of APC files.

I just download `xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6-installer.exe` and I download `php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip (2010-11-03 17:04 -0800)` and it works.

Comment: I unable to find this package php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip.I tried php_apc-3.1.10-5.3-vc9-x86.zip not working. any idea

Comment: @gowri, you download the vc9 version, make sure your php installation also is a vc9 by checking on phpinfo (Compiler section)

Comment: My compiler edition is **MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)**.What can i do ?

Comment: @gowri: it looks like the file has been removed. You can download latest version of XAMPP (1.7.7) It's VC9